# How to add date function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add (show too) 21 days to the 1st dose date if BioNTech was selected or add 28 days to the selected days if Sinovac was selected.

```
   Enter your First name:
    <br>
    <input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px"type="text" name="FName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <br>
    <br />
    Enter your Last name:
    <br />
    <input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px" type="text" name="LName" placeholder="First Name">
    <br>
    <br />
    Enter your Contact number:
    <br>
    <input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px" type="text" name="ContactN" placeholder="Contact">
    <br>
    <br />
    Enter the date of First Shot:
    <br>
    <input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px; font-size:20px" type="date" name="DateR" value="dd/mm/yy">
    <br>
    <br />
    Type of 1st Shot: 
    <p style="color: #C5C6C7">
        <input style="font-size:20px" type="radio" name="Fshot" value="BionTech" checked> BioNTech  &nbsp &nbsp
        <input style="font-size:20px" type="radio" name="Fshot" value="SinoVac"> SinoVac
    </p>
 

        </div>
    </center> 
    <br /><br>
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:22px" value="Book Now" class="hero-btn">
```

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you didn't show any effort from your side solving the problem. SO is not a free coding service. I just happened to be stuck on a train journey with a little time on my hands and put an answer together. Please follow the guidelines given here ([mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet should do the job:

```js
const d=document.querySelector("[name=DateR]"),
  d2=document.querySelector("[name=DateS]"),
  t=[...document.querySelectorAll("[name=Fshot]")];
d.addEventListener("change",addDate);
t.forEach(e=>e.onclick=addDate);

function addDate(){
  if(!d.value) return; // exit quietly if no date has yet been selected
  const dat=new Date(d.value);
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate()+
   (t.find(e=>e.checked).value==="BionTech"
  ? 21 : 28));
  d2.value=dat.toISOString().slice(0,10);
}
```

```html
<div>
Enter your First name:
<br>
<input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px"type="text" name="FName" placeholder="First Name">
<br>
<br />
Enter your Last name:
<br />
<input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px" type="text" name="LName" placeholder="Last Name">
<br>
<br />
Enter your Contact number:
<br>
<input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px;font-size:20px" type="text" name="ContactN" placeholder="Contact">
<br>
<br />
Enter the date of First Shot:
<br>
<input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px; font-size:20px" type="date" name="DateR" value="dd/mm/yy">
<br>
<br />
Type of 1st Shot: 
<p style="color: #C5C6C7">
    <input style="font-size:20px" type="radio" name="Fshot" value="BionTech" checked> BioNTech  &nbsp &nbsp
    <input style="font-size:20px" type="radio" name="Fshot" value="SinoVac"> SinoVac
</p>
<input font-size="30px" style="padding:10px; width:500px; font-size:20px" type="date" name="DateS" readonly>

 

    </div>
</center> 
<br /><br>
<input type="submit" style="font-size:22px" value="Book Now" class="hero-btn">
</div>
```

The universal event handling function `addDate()` does all the heavy work:

- it collects the first vaccination date and creates a Date() object `dat` from it
- it identifies which radio button was clicked and then adds 21 or 28 days to the Date object `dat`
- it then assigns the stringified value of `dat` to the second (readonly) date input field.

The JavaScript `Date` object allows for simple date adding by changing the "day of the month" part with `.setDate()`. The Date object converts "invalid" date numbers to valid dates by changing to the next month if necessary.

Comment: How would you say one could improve their coding ability?

Comment: :D good question! In the end you will need to keep an open mind, look around you and try out different things. Never be afraid to start with a completely new approach once you realize that the current one is not viable. I don't think there is a definite "shortcut" you can take.

Comment: Incidentally: I just changed the first line in my answer to avoid repetition: A constructor/deconstructor expression assigns the returned elements from the `["R","S"].map()` call to the constants `d` and `d2` in `[d,d2]`.

Comment: I always strive to produce concise code without redundancies or repetitions. As a result my code is not always easy to read, but hopefully reasonably easy to maintain.